# Using google api to get Calendar, Do each users have different access token or they all use same one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api

Im new to using APIs, if each users have different access tokens, how do i save all tokens in a secure way?

Right now, im just using a local file to save my credential file and token file.

I am still learning, it will be great if you give me advice on how to manage token files.